# Why do I get the error "variable 'color' might not have been initialized? Java

Tags: java, enums, var

So I'm making an UnoCard game that is played entirely in the console by computer players. I'm working on my UnoCard class and I've run into an error that I'm not sure how to solve. I've used enums for the colors and values. I get these error message for 2 lines of code: the following line of code (line 32) `private final Color color;` gives me this error message"variable value may not have been initialized" and this line of code (line 33) `private final Value value;` gives me this error message "variable color may not have been initialized". Following those errors, I have two more error messages: (line 35-38) `public UnoCard(final Color color, final Value value){this.color = color; this.value = value;}` "modifier public not allowed here" and "invalid method declaration: return type required". What is causing these errors and how do I fix them.

I've tried the following: for lines 32 and 33 I got rid of the final keyword and for lines 35-38 I added the enum Color as the return type but that doesn't make sense because I'm using to enums Color and Value.

Here is the code for my UnoCard class before I tried to fix it.

```
public class UnoCard {
    enum Color {
        RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, WILD;

        private static final Color[] colors = Color.values();
        public static Color getColor(int i){
            return Color.colors[i];
        }

        enum Value {
            ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, SKIP, DRAW_TWO, REVERSE, WILD, WILD_FOUR;
            private static final Value[] values = Value.values();
            public static Value getValue(int i){
                return Value.values[i];
            }
    }

    private final Color color;
    private final Value value;

    public UnoCard(final Color color, final Value value){
        this.color = color;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Color getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }

    public Value getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return color + "_" + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: You're missing a closing brace between your enum declarations.

Comment: why do you even have that colors array?

Comment: Typo Error  missing a closing brace }

Comment: sorry guys. I should've seen that.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `}` after

```
public static Color getColor(int i){
    return Color.colors[i];
}
```